# How to create toolbar tool on taskbar in windows 10 using c#

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, taskbar, windows-dev-center

I want to create a simple internet speed meter that displays speed right on top of the taskbar using windows toolbar feature on the taskbar but I don't know how to do so in C# or any other language. Please let me know how to do so.
[Toolbar in windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5OmP.png)

Comment: See: [C# NotifyIcon: Windows Forms](https://www.dotnetperls.com/notifyicon).

Comment: Thank you, but it is not for toolbar 

Comment: Hello, I noticed that you marked the UWP Tag. Are you using UWP for development? UWP currently does not provide related APIs for operating the toolbar

Comment: Can you please tell me what should I use, actually I am not a developer I have no idea :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a wonderful repo, called `TrafficMonitor`, which can meet your demands.

See https://github.com/zhongyang219/TrafficMonitor/blob/master/README_en-us.md

Comment: Thank you for this repo, this is really helpful

Comment: If you think the answer is helpfu, please consider accept it. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers